# Tomcat : java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, port, bind

I'm on Windows10 and downloaded Tomcat 8.5

I go to conf folder and run `startup.bat` script

After a few seconds, Tomcat stops. And in the logs I can see :

```
09-Jun-2021 21:52:01.433 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Démarrage du gestionnaire de protocole ["http-nio-8088"]
09-Jun-2021 21:52:01.484 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 748 ms
09-Jun-2021 21:52:01.491 GRAVE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:102)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:513)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:180)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:722)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

I understand I can change port in `server.xml` file (which I did).
My issue is no matter what port I choose (8081, 8082, 8083 etc...) I ALWAYS got this error :

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

What is wrong ? It's a computer from my company, is there some service, proxy preventing me from running Tomcat ?

The port I choose is free and available. After trying to launch Tomcat with a free port (8087 for example), I got this on command line :

```
C:\tools\apache-tomcat-8.5.66\bin>netstat -ano | find "8087"
  TCP    [fd5e:b41f:967b:1007:eca0:11ba:a1c9:bbbf]:58009  [fd5e:b41f:967b:1007:eca0:11ba:a1c9:bbbf]:8087  TIME_WAIT       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure isn't due by the port on which the HTTP connector listens, but the *"shutdown"* port (usually `8005`), which is already taken.

You configure it using the `port` attribute of the `<Server>` element:

```xml
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
...
</Server>
```

In most cases it is safe to disable it setting the value to `-1`. This will eliminate also a security threat: an attacker can shutdown the server by sending the characters `SHUTDOWN` to port `8005`.

Comment: Thanks you are correct. Looks like "8005" is often used on Windows10 btw.